# Periodicity inside time series: I have the period itself, how can I know where the periodicity started?

Tags: python, time-series, periodicity

I have a time-series that contains a hidden periodicity in the data.
I already found the period itself (e.g., 60 minutes, 100 minutes).
How can I find the specific sequence that has the periodicity? note that the periodicity can even start in the middle of the time series.

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [cycle detection algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection). If your cycle is exact they give you the cycle length and the stretch leading up to the first cycle.